# Eclipse PyDev doesn't see ones modules as imports and sees others in the same directory

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, pydev

The Python IDE plugin for Eclipse 'PyDev' on my Arch Linux machine doesn't see some modules as imports and sees other from one and the same directory: `/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload`:

```
import readline # <-- 'Unresolved import' error mark here
import select   # <-- 'Unresolved import' error mark here
import termios  # <-- 'Unresolved import' error mark here
import audioop  # <-- No error mark.
import parser   # <-- No error mark.
```

All these modules are residing in one directory. Moreover, those which are marked with 'Unresolved import' error - run without problems within PyDev itself (error marks are just red text editor embellishments, dynamically shown in the editor during the "coding time").

I know about`#@ UnresolvedImport` workaround, which simply ignores the error, but what can cause this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In the properties for your pydev project, there's a pane called "PyDev - PYTHONPATH", with a sub-pane called "External Libraries". You can add source folders (any folder that has an `__init__.py`) to the path using that pane. Your project code will then be able to import modules from those source folders

Comment: That directory is specified there. But it doesn't have `__init__.py`. It's a directory with compiled '.so' module files. One could think that PyDev cannot properly handle compiled modules, but some modules from that directory seem to be recognized OK by PyDev.

Comment: you need to add this empty file there.

Comment: I added the empty `__init__.py' to the directory with unresolved imports, refreshed the interpreter's configuration, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only 'correct' solution to this problem is to add problem modules to the 'forced builtins' in PyDev configuration.

Still, this problem seems like a PyDev bug, considering that a user should do additional manual configuration in order for standard python modules to work correctly. (If he/she manages to find info about needed configuration changes in the Web.)